# Better algorithm for checking time overlapping with N tasks

Tags: algorithm

First of all this is a discussion type question for suggestions. Say I have tasks with begin and end time, and when I create a new task I want to check time overlapping with all existing tasks efficiently. What i am currently using -

```
    checkTaskTimeOverlapping (List<Task> existingTasks, Task newTask){
       List<String> overlappingTimePeriods = new ArrayList<>();

       for(Task existingTask : existingTasks) {
           if( existingTask.beginTime < newTask.endTime && existingTask.endTime > newTask.beginTime) {
                  overlappingTimePeriods.add(existingTask.beginTime+ "-" + existingTask.endTime);     
             }  

       }
    }
```

Now as you can see, this Algorithm uses O(N) complexity to check time overlapping with N existing tasks. Now there's supposed to be a whole lot of tasks, So.. my question is, is there some way to better optimize this algorithm for checking time overlapping with existing tasks say less than O(N)? 
Or should I just keep the existing algorithm of O(N)

Comment: What can be the range for start and end times?

Comment: In minutes, so about 24 hours * 60 minutes 
starting from 1 - 12 in AM/PM format

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the existingTasks sorted by beginTime, and use Collections.binarySearch to obtain the index where to insert the new task, and compare with previous and next task.
That, of course would be O(log(N))

Comment: 1. Wouldn't it take O(NLog(N)) to sort it first if it's taken from database in unOrdered state ?
2. Even then would I be able get the overlappingTimePeriods list ?

Comment: @adn.911 You can't improve performance beyond O(n) without keeping intermediate results stored somewhere or enforcing additional constraints on the input such as it being ordered.

Comment: @adn.911 1. yes 2. assuming the database contains only non-overlapping tasks, the task before the insertion point may (or may not) overlap (if existingTasks[i-1].endTime > newTask.beginTime), all the tasks that follow the insertion point until existingTasks[j].beginTime  > newTask.endTime (for j >= i) is to be added to the list. As soon this condition is not met, you can stop searching.